# Load jquery function upon completing a text input

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Is it possible to load a jquery function right after the user has completed a text input (not on form submission)?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['textinput'])) {echo "loadjqfunction()";}
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are mixing server and client processing. What is telling you that a text input has been completed? Blur?  $(function() { $("#textinput").on("blur",loadjqfunction) });

Comment: Any idea how can I accomplish this in another way?

Comment: what do you mean/consider by "has completed a text input" ? a focus on next element or on the click of a button/link?

Comment: When the input value changes, I want to load a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be done entirely in Javascript:

```
$("#textinput").change(loadjqfunction);
```